# how to get a popup when someone has connected to particular database

Tags: linux, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, toad

Is there any way i can write a script to get a popup as an email that some x user has connected to a particular database

Scenario: there was an "X" database and if some "ABC" user has logged into that database by using some account user id and password , an email should be triggered to some contacts : saying -- that particular user has connected to that database.

We are currently using Toad / Sql Developer as a third party tools to connect to oracle database.

Is there any way i can achieve this by righting a sql procedure or shell script or any other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to create an `AFTER LOGON` trigger, e.g.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_user_connected
   AFTER LOGON
   ON DATABASE
DECLARE
  l_global_name varchar2(30);
BEGIN
   SELECT global_name
     INTO l_global_name
     FROM global_name;

   UTL_MAIL.send (sender      => 'noreply@orcl',
                  recipients  => 'avinash@gmail.com',
                  cc          => NULL,
                  bcc         => NULL,
                  mime_type   => NULL,
                  subject     => 'Logged right now into ' || l_global_name,
                  MESSAGE     => USER);
END;
/
```

You'll probably want to restrict it, somehow (otherwise your inbox will explode :)).

**[EDIT: dropping an object]**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_bd
   AFTER DROP
   ON SCHEMA
DECLARE
   oper  VARCHAR2 (100);
BEGIN
   SELECT ora_sysevent INTO oper FROM DUAL;

   IF oper = 'DROP'
   THEN
      utl_mail.send ...
   END IF;
END;
/
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. on the place of "DATABASE" can i pass it my database name (i mean host name ) so that i can use this as a generic script. Is it possible..

Comment: i am getting "insufficient privileges" on 3rd line "DATABASE". Is there any way i can solve it or do i need to get permission from our DBA to give access..

Comment: You're welcome. Nope. DATABASE is a keyword. Create such a trigger in all your databases, it already *is* generic. In order to get the database name (and put it into, for example, subject), use e.g. `select global_name from global_name;`.

Comment: As of insufficient privileges: you have to have rights to create such a trigger. You'll need to talk to your DBA because it can be created by (for example) SYS, SYSTEM or user with DBA role granted.

Comment: Is this syntax works : subject     => 'select global_name from global_name'    .. Or any other change. ?

Comment: No; select it into a variable, and use the variable as a subject.

Comment: Thanks a lot. As for some of the databases we may use some generic user id/ password logins. Can i get the desktop name as well which user has connected so that we can track it. ( Example. I want to get details from Monitor -> Session browser and get all the users. so that if they are using generic user id also i can get there original names )

Comment: Try `select SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'OS_USER') from dual;`. Check documentation for other values SYS_CONTEXT returns, maybe you'll find something interesting.

Comment: I have one doubt. Please help me with your suggestion..

I have 2 different environments for an oracle database. ( Example: Development environment & Test Environment ).

If i have logged into Development environment , a pop-up should be displayed saying " This is a development environment ".

Currently we have oracle database and we are using Toad/ Sql developer as a 3rd party tools to connect to that database.

Is there any way i can achieve and create any popup like that ..?

Comment: If there is a way, I don't know it. I use TOAD and have 159 connections. Visually, I distinguish them by **colors** (all connections to the same server share the same color).

Comment: (Just to mention: when you said "you marked your vote", I'm not sure I understand what you meant by saying that. If some answer *answers* your question, you can *upvote* it, but you should *accept* that answer as well).

Comment: Right; it has just appeared. Thank you.

Comment: Can we right a trigger in the same way : If some one has ran the Drop or truncate , immediately mail should be send "saying tablename has been dropped by a particular user "